# Is there any way to extract the Revit model warning message by forge api?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there any way to extract the Revit model warning message by forge API?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Revit API provides the [Document.GetWarnings method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/4774613d-600a-e1b5-b5aa-f1ee3b14394c.htm) for this. You can call this method in the Forge context using [Forge Design Automation for Revit](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview), aka [DA4R](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.55).